# MULE ESB Batch Processing

Tags: database, logging, mule, batch-processing

I am trying to use a batch scope in mule. So in the Input of the batch I am fetching data from database which returns a collection. Now when the control of the batch reaches Process records no execution happens. Whatever I specify in the batch step is not getting executed. Not even if I try and print a simple hello in a logger.

my output in the console looks like:

```
INFO  2014-11-26 21:55:16,534 [pool-13-thread-1] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Created instance ce4bbeae-7588-11e4-9ab0-1458d0b93b2f for batch job pocBatch1
INFO  2014-11-26 21:55:16,534 [pool-13-thread-1] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Starting input phase
INFO  2014-11-26 21:55:16,659 [pool-13-thread-1] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Input phase completed
INFO  2014-11-26 21:55:16,674 [pool-13-thread-1] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Starting loading phase for instance 'ce4bbeae-7588-11e4-9ab0-1458d0b93b2f' of job 'pocBatch1'
INFO  2014-11-26 21:55:16,706 [pool-13-thread-1] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Finished loading phase for instance ce4bbeae-7588-11e4-9ab0-1458d0b93b2f of job pocBatch1. 3 records were loaded
INFO  2014-11-26 21:55:16,721 [pool-13-thread-1] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Started execution of instance 'ce4bbeae-7588-11e4-9ab0-1458d0b93b2f' of job 'pocBatch1'
```

Comment: did you find an answer to it - please post it. I am facing the same issue

Comment: Am Facing the same issue,have you found the solution?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar, I too had a similar problem which I solved through looking at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642320/why-batch-scope-behave-strange-when-trying-to-load-a-huge-records-mule-esb). Deleting the .mule folder worked for me and when running in standalone, outside of Studio, I didn't see the same issue

Comment: @Jaguar please see my comment above as to how I solved this

Answer (score 0):

Wit this information I can only that you have a too strict filter on the phase. Please refer to [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Filters+and+Batch+Commit#BatchFiltersandBatchCommit-Filters) part of the batch documentation where the accept filters are discussed.